# How to set a metrics join to another job

Tags: prometheus

I have two jobs,this:

```
- job: job_1
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.1.1:7777']
- job: job_2
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.1.1:8888']
```

and

```
job_1 have metric name: 
kube_node_work{node:192.168.1.1,work_1:value_1....}  # job_1 have much metrics

job_2 have metric name: 
kube_node_home{instance：192.168.1.1,home_1:value_2....} #  have 17 labels
```

how to set it can look like this?

```
# "kube_node_home" add to job_1 (every metrics)
kube_node_work{node:192.168.1.1,work_1:value_1,home_1:value_2....}
```

Comment: What is "label_1:value_1" in your expected output? I fail to see it in input.

Comment: Also, are those 17 labels have constant names?

Comment: my bad , I have modified the  label ,and those 17 labels is constant names